# `error' called with 1 args to fill 0 format field(s)

Tags: byte-compilation

I'm getting an [`error called with 1 args to fill 0 format field(s)`](https://travis-ci.org/clojure-emacs/cider/jobs/256296466#L1213) error when byte-compiling [`cider-repl-history.el`](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/9773544cffa7a7bedf131152ade88d7137f20182/cider-repl-history.el?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L422) with Emacs 24.4 and 24.5. No such error is reported for Emacs 25.1.

Line 422 of `cider-repl-history.el` is a `cl-assert`. The docstring for `cl-assert` says:

> Other args STRING and ARGS... are arguments to be passed to `error'.

In this case we are passing in a `STRING`, but no `ARGS`. I suspect this is a resolved bug, but I'm can't find anything by [searching the bug archive](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/search.cgi?phrase=%22called+with%22&search=search&skip=0&order_field=&order_operator=STRA&max_results=10).

How is this best handled? We have `byte-compile-error-on-warn` set to `t`.

Comment: I think you'll see the problem if you macroexpand that `cl-assert` call under 24.5.

Comment: I must be missing something. Byte-compiling `(cl-assert (overlayp "foo") t "not an overlay")` on Emacs 24.5.50.1 is just fine. The result of `macroexpand-all` on that form is: `(progn
  (or
   (overlayp "foo")
   (error "not an overlay"))
  nil)`, which seems just fine.

Comment: Oh...I think I got it. If the form evaluates to something *non-constant*, *and* `show-args` is `t`, we get [`(error string ,@sargs ,@args)`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-24/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-macs.el#L2694) in Emacs 24. Lovely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cl-assert` has a signature like:

```el
(form &optional show-args string &rest args)
```

We should not set `show-args` to `t` unless we want the args to `form` to be format args to `string`. This can be seen in the [definition of `cl-assert`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-24/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-macs.el#L2694) under Emacs 24 and in the [definition of `cl--assertion-failed`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-25/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-preloaded.el#L50) under Emacs 25.

E.g.

```el
(defvar obj nil)

(macroexpand-all '(cl-assert (overlayp obj) t "not overlay"))
;; => (progn
;;     (or
;;      (overlayp obj)
;;      (error "not overlay" obj))      ;; `error' called with 1 args to fill 0 format field(s)
;;     nil)
```

The args to `form` are only given to `string` if they [do not all expand to constants](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-24/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-macs.el#L2687-L2690). E.g.

```el
(macroexpand-all '(cl-assert (overlayp "foo") t "not overlay"))    
;; => (progn
;;     (or
;;      (overlayp "foo")
;;      (error "not an overlay"))       ;; OK
;;     nil)
```

The byte-compiler doesn't complain in Emacs 25 like in Emacs 24, but we should be setting `show-args` to `nil` in any case.

Thanks to @npostavs for the hint.